How do I uniquely identify faces in real assemblies?
I am writing some code that needs to uniquely identify a specific geometric entity in a CAD assembly based on a set of parameters. FWIW, I also have control over the code that measures these parameters.
My question is whether the following sets of parameters are sufficient to uniquely specify the geometry:
For parts/bodies:

Volume
Surface Area
Center of Volume

For faces:

Area
Total Edge Length
Geometric Centroid
Surface Normal at Centroid

For edges:

Length
Midpoint
Orientation at Midpoint
Radius of curvature at the Midpoint

All these entities are for physically realistic bodies, so there should be no self-intersecting surfaces, and distinct surfaces should not be intersecting either.
So, can the above sets of parameters uniquely specify the corresponding geometric entity type?
EDIT:
Some definitions:
Geometric Entity: An object the is created in a CAD software and is either directly associated with or derived from (e.g., by midsurfacing) manufacturable parts. This may be a solid body, surface body, or line body. It may also be a face that is a part of a solid body or surface body. Finally, it may be an edge that is part of any of the previously mentioned entities.
Physically Realistic: Means the entity could exist as a tangible object. So, self-intersecting surfaces would be excluded. It would not necessarily need to have an interior however since surface bodies would eventually have a thickness defined to make them represent something like a sheet metal part. There are no restrictions on whether the entity is convex, concave, smooth, etc.
More context:
I'm writing a script to find geometric entities associated with boundary conditions, contacts, mesh definitions, etc. based on defined properties for a workflow automation in Ansys Mechanical. I'm trying to keep the limitations to a minimum, but am also aware that the tool is not likely to encounter geometry that is insanely complex.
EDIT 2:
Some Examples:
Here's a screenshot of the geometry in the STEP file here: link.

Here are the parameters for each entity:
Solid Body: Cube
    Volume: 0.001
    Area: 0.06
    Centroid: [0, 0, 0.05]
Solid Body: Sphere
    Volume: 0.000523598775598299
    Area: 0.0313273957826823
    Centroid: [0, 0.2, 0]
Solid Body: Torus
    Volume: 0.001
    Area: 8.582478951e-002
    Centroid: [0, 0, 0.05]

Face: Top of Bottom Cube
    Area: 0.01
    Perimeter: 0.4
    Centroid: [0, 0, 0.1]
    Normal: [0, 0, 1]
Face: Bottom of Top Cube
    Area: 0.01
    Perimeter: 0.4
    Centroid: [0, 0, 0.1]
    Normal: [0, 0, -1]

Surface: Square
    Area: 0.01
    Perimeter: 0.4
    Centroid: [0.2, 0, 0.1]
    Normal: [0, 0, 1]
Surface: Partial Cylinder Face
    Area: 0.01
    Perimeter: 0.4
    Centroid: [0.2, 0, 0.107935671653342]
    Normal: [0, 0, 1]
Surface: Ring
    Area: 0.01
    Perimeter: 1.012670731
    Centroid: [0.2, 0, 0.1]
    Normal: [0, 0, 1]

Edge: Straight
    Length: 0.1
    Midpoint: [0.4, -0.05, 0.1]
    Orientation at Midpoint: [1, 0, 0]
    Radius of Curvature at Midpoint: NaN
Edge: Arc
    Length: 0.1
    Midpoint: [0.4, -0.05, 0.107950801669577]
    Orientation at Midpoint: [1, 0, 0]
    Radius of Curvature at Midpoint: 0.05
Edge: Circle
    Length: 0.1
    Midpoint: [0.4, -0.05, 0.1]
    Orientation at Midpoint: [0, -0.990068959096359, -0.140582560205213]
    Radius of Curvature at Midpoint: 1.591549431e-002

Obviously, these can be distinguished with the parameters I'm capturing. I'm trying to understand if there are cases I've not thought of where the listed parameters would not be sufficient to distinguish between the different geometric entities.

Please [edit] the question to provide clear definitions of "geometric entity" and "physically realistic". Must it be convex? Have an interior? If it's not just a polyhedron, what does it mean to talk about faces and edges and "parts"? How smooth must those be? Several examples would help us help you. (Don't use comments to clarify. [edit] the question.)

Did that clarify some things?

Better, but still unclear. If you could show us pictures of, say,  three sample objects along with the data you hope determines each I might understand better. Make one really easy/obvious and the others subtler. What would your data look like for a sphere? A hemisphere like half a grapefruit? A hollow hemisphere like a grapefruit after you've eaten it?We need lots of examples.

@EthanBolker I've added specific examples. Others could be added, but I think what I've got should give you a decent idea.

This helps a lot. Perhaps I understand. You don't have to characterize the shape of an object abstractly - you just want to be able to identify the objects in a set  of objects using some of their attributes. I don't think that's possible. You should be able to imagine to solids with the same volume, surface area and center of gravity. Try that with a torus and a horizontal rod through the hole. (If these are objects in a cad system, I would hope that the system let you name them with unique identifiers. Then you wouldn't need natural parameters of the object to determine them.)

Thanks. It does look like a torus and a cylinder would be a case where, if the dimensions were just right the volume, surface area, and center of volume could all match without the two bodies interfering. I guess that leaves me with the option of either trying to get the moments off inertia for the body or just living with the limitation.

Live with it. I suspect there is no finite set of invariants that will do what you want.

True. But at the same time, the more invariants that are added, the more improbable it will be to have two bodies that are indistinguishable. So, I'll look to see if the moments of inertia are easily obtainable. If they are, I'll include them.
